# Adding delay to make animation smoother

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am using a windows store 8.1 app where I need a delay to show animation smoother. But delay is appearing for more time than expected. I did like this

```
 Animation1.Begin();
 await Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync(async (s) =>
         {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        await MainViewModel.Instance.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
         {
        MessageDialog.Show("after delay");
         });
         }, Windows.System.Threading.WorkItemPriority.High);
```

Comment: `But delay is appearing for more time than expected.` How much time you want to delay?

Comment: Just 1 sec to finish animation. but it is appearing more than 1 second in UI.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Delay is set in milliseconds so ideally for 1 second delay you have to do Task.Delay(1000). And there are other overloaded methods for delay as well. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Other thing I see is the method you have used to show message uses a messagebox which is only Windows 8 thing. In Windows 8.1 you need to use MessageDialog and if MessageBox is your custom class which internally uses MessageDialog then the showing part needs to be awaited.

Comment: Then why not set the duration property in the storyboard itself? Plus please add all the proper details in your question.

Comment: yes. duration of 1sec  is applied in storyboard itself. animation is applied while unloading a page and then next page come. So inorder to make animation more prominent,i made this delay but this delay is taking more time than 1 sec.

Comment: so loading of second page is slow.